# Design of similar typed classes

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, class-design

I am designing classes to represent geometric objects such as vectors. I need to define methods such as addition, scalar multiplication, dot product and others. The vector coordinates can be integers or reals of different sizes, hence the need to replicate the classes corresponding to these different types.

E.g.

```
class intVector
{
   int X, Y;

   intVector& operator+=(const intVector& A) { … }
   intVector& operator*=(int A) { … }

   float Norm(); // Not int
};

class floatVector
{
   float X, Y;

   floatVector& operator+=(const floatVector& A) { … }
   floatVector& operator*=(float A) { … }

   float Norm(); // Would be double for a doubleVector
};
```

(I also need binary operators defined as functions rather than methods.)

I want to avoid/minimize code duplication, so using templates seems a natural approach. Anyway, I want my classes to appear as plain classes, not templated ones (one option is to derive from a templated class; another is to typedef class specializations).

In addition, there is a nasty constraint: not all methods make sense for all data types and shouldn't be declared at all in some classes, or there can be special cases with the types of certain arguments.

During my attempts, I faced numerous problems such as the need to add numerous explicit instantiations, difficulty to avoid the members that don't make sense, cast issues between the base/derived classes… making the whole design painful. all in all, I spend writing more code with templates than without !

Have you experienced similar class designs ? Is there a classical way to solve this ?

Comment: Use a template maybe?

Comment: `template + alias == success`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: hem, I mention that in my post.

Comment: @NathanOliver: can you elaborate ? In my attempts, typedefs over templates do not address the requirement of special cases. The devil is in the details.

Answer (score 1):

Templates are the right way to handle this.  What you can do is add overloads for the different functions that need to behave differently and use [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) to constrain them to the types they are needed for.  Using a template we can combine both classes into a generic `Vector` class and then use a [type alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) to get concrete names for the different types.  That would look like

```
template<typename T>
class Vector
{
   T X, Y;

   Vector& operator+=(const Vector& A) { … }
   Vector& operator*=(T A) { … }

   template<typename U = T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<U>, bool> = true>
   correct_size_floating_point_type<U> Norm() { integer code } 
   template<typename U = T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<U>, bool> = true>
   U Norm() { floating point code }
};

using intVector = Vector<int>;
using floatVector = Vector<float>;
```

Where `correct_size_floating_point_type` is a template type that returns a correctly sized floating point type for the supplied integer type.